# JQuery .scroll() event to show hidden object does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-events

I'm using `.scroll()` in order to make the image `#mag` visible once I scroll past a certain point.

```
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
                var scroll_pos_test = 1000;             

                if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
                    $("#mag").css("visibility","visible");
                }
            });
```

---

```
        <img id= "mag" src="assets/maginatransparent.png" style = "visibility: hidden; position: fixed; height: 40vh; bottom: 30vh; right: 0">
```

When I run this, I get no errors, but the event doesn't seem to have been triggered even when I scroll past 1000px.

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/k04qck9h/
Note this uses a `span` instead of an `img.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$(window).scrollTop();`

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {
        var y_scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var scroll_pos_test = 1000;             

        if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
            $("#mag").css("visibility","visible");
        }else{
            $("#mag").css("visibility","hidden");
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/k04qck9h/3/)

Comment: @SemicolonExpected it should work man .. please check you include jquery library .. and wait for demo

Comment: I did, jquery 1.11.2 `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">` I also get no console errors which usually happens if I don't include jQuery

Comment: I created a jsfiddle link. Not sure if I did it right though

Comment: That's odd, your demo worked, but the one I linked even when I added the `else` and the `document.ready()` still doesn't work.